# How to make right friends system?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have this table. It's working perfectly, but looks awful:

```
id | username      | friend
----------------------------------
1  | kayover       | random_user
2  | random_user   | kayover
3  | random_user   | random_user_3
4  | kayover       | random_user_2
5  | random_user_2 | random_user_3
```

How can I have more organized table, that will look at least like this?:

```
id | username      | friend
-----------------------------------------------
1  | kayover       | random_user, random_user_2
2  | random_user   | kayover, random_user_3
3  | random_user_2 | random_user_3
```

P.S. Friends can be NOT mutual, requests for friendship is missing.

Comment: *"How can I have more organized table, that will look at least like this?"* - Don't, you should be normalizing your db, not using comma-separated values. Those will give you trouble down the road.

Comment: However, you can `CONCAT()` on the output, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What are you mean by **normalizing**?

Comment: Well, you would normally have a separate table for username, with IDs, and then you would have a table consisting of only IDs, not the names - that will be faster when fetching specific values based on IDs, and you'll just fetch the names from the user-table with a join.

Comment: the best way is to solve that, get it to first normal form,  http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php

Comment: I agree with other comments -- the "more organized" version looks `awful`, but from a database format.

Answer (score 0):

According to first normal form you table will,

```
id | username      | friend
-----------------------------------------------
1  | kayover       | random_user, random_user_2
2  | random_user   | kayover, random_user_3
3  | random_user_2 | random_user_3


id   | friend
----------------------------------
1    | random_user
1    | random_user_2
2    | kayover
2    | random_user_3
3    | random_user_3
```

in database management, you need to keep the database in the best way of efficiency.

your can follow more on this link [click here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get "organized" *during* `SELECT` by using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT username, GROUP_CONCAT(friend) AS friends
    FROM `awful`;
```